# Type mismatch VBA error in a variable declared as string

Tags: excel, vba

I don't understand the code below, please help.

It keeps on returning a type mismatch error against the variable b.

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As String

a = InputBox("Input the number of items", "Total Number of Items.")
b = InputBox("Which Block?", "Total Number of Items.")

Do While b <> "a" Or "A" Or "B" Or "b"
        MsgBox ("Invalid Block. Try again, Input A or B")
        b = InputBox("Which Block?", "SELECT BLOCK.")
Loop
     If b = "a" Or "A" Then
        Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a3:a39").Value
    Else
        Me.ComboBox2.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a3:a35").Value
    End If
```

Comment: @JüriRuut, I have tried the code
    Do While b <> "a" Or b <> "A" Or b <> "B" Or b <> "b"
but the loop won't stop even if I already input A or B.. It keeps on showing the msgbox. I had to use the task manager to stop it...

Comment: Didn't look too thoroughly into the contents :-( Instead of task manager, Ctrl-Break can be used to stop executing the code.

Comment: I think a simple solution is  `b = CStr(InputBox("Which Block?", "Total Number of Items."))` and also the line: `b = CStr(InputBox("Which Block?", "SELECT BLOCK."))`

Comment: may I know which lane of code is it type mismatching?

Comment: it's when I input a or A in the b = inputbox..

Comment: Can you update us with the codes you have in hand now? Thanks!

Comment: Let me clarify the problem now, if you enter for example "Larry" in B, it won't pop `Type MisMatch` ?   And after it appears `Type Mismatch`, you click `Debug` , which line of code it is highlighting?

Comment: I'm not sure but There's no highlighted line.. Maybe I should post the whole code?

Here's what happened:
When I press F5, an input box appear asking the number of items. Then another inputbox appear asking if block a or b then it will return the type mismatch error...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21125/discussion-between-larry-and-ailen-samson-laguda)

Comment: @ailen I have rolled back your code to your initial question. Overwriting your initial question with my answer and then adding further code muddled the Q&A sequence. If you want to start working with an answer inside your question then in future pls add it as a separate piece of code (at bottom of the original question) and make it clear you have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a logical flaw. Change

`Do While UCase$(b) <> "A" or UCase$(b) <> "B"`

INTO

`Do While UCase$(b) <> "A" AND UCase$(b) <> "B"`

Comment: I have tried it as well, and the loop won't stop...keeps on returning the inputbox...

Comment: This was already correct in my initial code, the OP did not use it as I had posted.

Comment: @brettdj  hi sorry i did not go through all the codes...just the title one...and i didnt copy ur answer.. u can see from the chat in the question i go through the debug stage and make my own answer.

Comment: @brettdj my apologize again, do I need to close this answer?

Comment: @Larry , I have removed the -1 as the OP did confuse matters by editing the initial question and I accept that you corrected the issue the OP added to my working code in good faith. No need to close or change anything (I edited your code so I could remove the downvote)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Application.InputBox` to force a text input for `a` and and numeric input for `b`

Using `UCASE$` shortens your testing

```
Dim a As Long
Dim b As String

a = Application.InputBox("Input the number of items", "Total Number of Items.", , , , , , 1)
b = Application.InputBox("Which Block?", "Total Number of Items.", , , , , 2)

Do While UCase$(b) <> "A" And UCase$(b) <> "B"
b = Application.InputBox("Which Block?", "Invalid Entry - Total Number of Items.", , , , , 2)
Loop
```

Comment: type mismatch when I type A?

Comment: Are you typing *A* against the prompt for `b`?

Comment: yes, I should input A or B in the b = Application.InputBox("Which Block?", "Total Number of Items.", , , , , 2) and the loop must end  if its not A or B or a or b, another inputbox must appear..

But when I type A or B, its Type mismatch error...?

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. What happens if you try `Dim b` rather than `Dim b as String`?

Comment: @AilenSamsonLaguda why did you accept the "answer" from Larry that was copied from this question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you test the "b" variable.

Wrong

```
Do While b <> "a" Or "A" Or "B" Or "b"
```

Right

```
Do While b <> "a" Or b <> "A" Or b <> "B" Or b <> "b"
```

The same applies to the if Clause

Istead of

```
If b = "a" Or "A" Then
```

use

```
If b = "a" Or b = "A" Then
```

**EDIT:**

When you used the correct syntax for the Do Loop, your code entered into an infinite loop because of how you constructed the While conditions.
For example, if the inputBox retrieves "B", it is sill "<>b" or "<>a" or... and therefore it will enter the loop again.  Whatever the user inputs, it will always be different from any of the other conditions.

**EDIT 2:**

Please try this.  Doe it retrieves the same error?

```
Sub TryThis()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As String

    a = InputBox("Input the number of items", "Total Number of Items.")
    b = InputBox("Which Block?", "Total Number of Items.")

    Do While b <> "a" And b <> "A" And b <> "B" And b <> "b"
            MsgBox ("Invalid Block. Try again, Input A or B")
            b = InputBox("Which Block?", "SELECT BLOCK.")
    Loop

    Debug.Print "InputBox b Correctly filled"

    If b = "a" Or b = "A" Then
        Debug.Print "User Input A"
    Else
        Debug.Print "User Input: " & b
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I saw that him posted the `RIGHT` one in OP's own question's comment. I think he changed that?

Comment: I have tried this already:

Do While b <> "a" Or b <> "A" Or b <> "B" Or b <> "b"


But still type mismatch..

Comment: I missed that comment. Thanks for pointing it our @Larry.  I edited the answer to address the issue.

Comment: Did you changed it in both the While conditions and the If conditions?